# In formatted bibliography, authors' names are repeated and go outside margin

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using bibliography style `spbasic`. In the references, the text goes outside the set margin, and also authors names are repeated. How to avoid this problem with the same bibliogrpahy style? As below `"DeCandia et al(2007)DeCandia, Hastorun, Jampani, Kakulapati, Lakshman, Pilchin, subramanian, Vosshall, and Vogels."` are all typeset in the same line, which goes outside margin. Below this line I am getting the same authors' names again but this time it stays within margin. How I can remove first line or remove second line and first line within margin.

> DeCandia et al(2007)DeCandia, Hastorun, Jampani, Kakulapati, Lakshman, Pilchin, subramanian, Vosshall, and Vogels.
>   DeCandia G, Hastorun D, Jampani M, Kakulapati G, Lakshman A, Pilchin
>   A, subramanian SS, Vosshall P, Vogels W (2007) Dynamo: amazon’s highly
>   available key-value store. In: Proceedings of the 21st ACM Symposium on
>   Operating Systems Principles 2007, SOSP 2007, Stevenson, Washington,
>   USA, October 14-17, 2007, pp 205–220, DOI 10.1145/1294261.1294281, URL
>   http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1294261.1294281
>
> Di et al(2013)Di, Robert, Vivien, Kondo, Wang, and Cappello. Di S, Robert Y, Vivien F,
>   Kondo D, Wang C, Cappello F (2013) Optimization of cloud task processing with
>   checkpoint-restart mechanism. In: International Conference for High Performance
>   Computing, Networking, Storage and Analysis, SC’13, Denver, CO, USA - November 17
>   - 21, 2013, pp 64:1–64:12, DOI 10.1145/2503210.2503217, URL http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2503210.2503217"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the header of Springer's `spbasic.bst` bibliography style file :

> % This bibliography style file is intended for texts in ENGLISH
>
> % This is an author-year citation style bibliography. As such, it is
>
> % non-standard LaTeX, and requires a special package file to function properly.
>
> % Such a package is    natbib.sty   by Patrick W. Daly

In short, you need to load the `natbib` package in preamble, preferably as follows:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
```

Then, be sure to re-run (pdf)LaTeX.

Type `texdoc natbib` at a command prompt to bring up the user guide of the `natbib` package. Do familiarize yourself with the `natbib` package's specialized commands for creating citation call-outs, such as `\citet`, `\citep`, `\citeauthor`, `\citealt`, `\citealp`, and quite a few more.

Here's the output of a full MWE (minimum working example) that implements the suggestion to load the `natbib` package; observe the use of `\citet` and `\citep` to generate text-style and parenthetic-style citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% Aside: Raw bib data obtained from 
%% https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1294261.1294281
%% and
%% https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2503210.2503217
%% (Click on the "BibTeX" button on the right-hand edges of the pages.)
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{DeCandia:2007:DAH:1294261.1294281,
 author = {DeCandia, Giuseppe and Hastorun, Deniz and Jampani, Madan and Kakulapati, Gunavardhan and Lakshman, Avinash and Pilchin, Alex and Sivasubramanian, Swaminathan and Vosshall, Peter and Vogels, Werner},
 title = {Dynamo: Amazon's Highly Available Key-value Store},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of Twenty-first ACM SIGOPS Symposium on Operating Systems Principles},
 series = {SOSP~'07},
 year = {2007},
 isbn = {978-1-59593-591-5},
 location = {Stevenson, Washington, USA},
 pages = {205--220},
 numpages = {16},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1294261.1294281},
 doi = {10.1145/1294261.1294281},
 acmid = {1294281},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {performance, reliability, scalability},
} 
@inproceedings{Di:2013:OCT:2503210.2503217,
 author = {Di, Sheng and Robert, Yves and Vivien, Fr{\'e}d{\'e}ric and Kondo, Derrick and Wang, Cho-Li and Cappello, Franck},
 title = {Optimization of Cloud Task Processing with Checkpoint-restart Mechanism},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the International Conference on High Performance Computing, Networking, Storage and Analysis},
 series = {SC~'13},
 year = {2013},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-2378-9},
 location = {Denver, Colorado},
 pages = {64:1--64:12},
 articleno = {64},
 numpages = {12},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2503210.2503217},
 doi = {10.1145/2503210.2503217},
 acmid = {2503217},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {BLCR, checkpoint-restart mechanism, cloud computing, google, optimal checkpointing interval},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % for well-formatted URL strings
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib} % citation management package
\bibliographystyle{spbasic} % select a suitable bibliography style

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{DeCandia:2007:DAH:1294261.1294281}, 
\citep{Di:2013:OCT:2503210.2503217}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ASHISHKUMARMISHRAphd - You're most welcome! By the way, if you feel that this answer fully solved your issue, feel free to "accept" it (by clicking on the checkmark symbol near the top-left. ;-)